# Save the file On directory folder

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, extjs

I have problem with save the browse file to local directory folder.
I am usimg extJs as client side and C# .net as server side.
I  browse file from extjs and pass only file name(not entire path) it to ashx handler.and in ashx handler i want to save this file into directory folder.

How can i do this?

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: I do not code so for.Becouse i not getting any idea how to do that

Answer (score 0):

File upload in JavaScipt:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/FileGuide/FileUpDown

note: if you want to do this in IE then use a jQuery plugin sice IE does not support formdata and makes it hard to write the JavaScript code yourself.

Handle upload in C#
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323246

Sorry for not posting code but there is just a little bit too much involved to do it right.